# Unable to access function declared in the <script> block resting in <head>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a script which takes data from a form and creates a dynamic table using a function. i.e when I click on a specific button, a row gets added to the table and new table is displayed. I have tried keeping the form and the function both in the script, script in the head and form in body but nothing works!

```
<head>
    <script>

        function addData() {
            var baseid = getElementById("baseID");
            var sauceid = getElementById("sauceID");
            var toppingsid = getElementById("toppingsID");

            var table = getElementById("dynamictable");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount)

            row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = baseid.value;
            row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = sauceid.value;
            row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = toppingsid.value;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Base&nbsp
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id='baseID' style='width:150px'>
                    <option value='Regular'>Regular</option>
                    <option value='Regular'>Thin</option>
                    <option value='Regular'>Cheese Burst</option>
                    <option value='Regular'>Wheat</option>
                    <option value='Regular'>Multi-grain</option>
                    <option value='Regular'>Thin wheat</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Sauce&nbsp
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id='sauceID' style='width:150px'>
                    <option value='Margarhita'>Margarhita</option>
                    <option value='Pesto'>Pesto</option>
                    <option value='Bechamel'>Bechamel</option>
                    <option value='Salsa'>Salsa</option>
                    <option value='BBQ'>BBQ</option>
                    <option value='Pepper Jelly'>Pepper Jelly</option>
                    <option value='Romesco'>Romesco</option>
                    <option value='Thai Chilly'>Thai Chilly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Toppings&nbsp
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='toppingsID' style='width:146px'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align='center'>
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="adddata()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br /><br />

    <table border=1 id="dynamictable" style="width:450px">
        <caption style="margin-bottom:7px"><b><u>Order</u></b></caption>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width=150px><b>Base</b></td>
            <td align="center" width=150px><b>Sauce</b></td>
            <td align="center" width=150px><b>Toppings</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Javascript function names are case-sensitive - yours don't match

Comment: still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global `getElementById()` function. It's `document.getElementById()`. Also you named your function `addData()` but your HTML event handler calls it `adddata()`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Keep your developer console open when testing your code.

Comment: i write the code in notepad++ there is no developer console.

Comment: When you run it in your browser there certainly is a developer console.

Comment: Thanks anyway, the code runs flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo where you are adding the function to the button.
2. Use document.getElementById(). Not getElementById() by itself.
3. Also, your addData() will not add data dynamically. Refer to: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)